# How to pass dalvik command line parameters through .apk?

Tags: java, android

I know that it is possible to launch java program in Android in a such way:

```
adb push "hello_world.zip" $REMOTE_PATH/
adb shell mkdir $REMOTE_PATH/dalvik-cache
adb shell dalvikvm -cp "$REMOTE_PATH/hello_world.zip" -Xint:portable -Xdexopt:none -Xverify:none hello_world
```

It's very good!

But now I want to create Android .apk file. And I want this application to be launched with the same command line parameters `"-Xint:portable -Xdexopt:none -Xverify:none"` automatically.

I assume that parameters names may differ from this `"-Xint:portable -Xdexopt:none -Xverify:none"`, but functionality must be the same. I have no idea what I have to do and google doesn't want to help me to solve this issue. 
Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: You may have to use normal app code to launch a unique dvm for your special code as in your example, but realize this is both inefficient and likely to have difficulty interacting with the platform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain that you can't. You can change the system-wide interpreter mode with `setprop dalvik.vm.execution-mode int:portable` but you would need root. I don't know of any way to disable `dexopt` for your process only (that would be a security risk!). You most certainly can't touch the bootclasspath (which is the classpath that your app initially runs under).

I believe you can disable `jnicheck` for your process but that's about it.

Apps on the device run via `app_process` and the zygote, you can think of them as restricted wrappers around Dalvik. There are no `dalvikvm` invocations apart from the initial zygote one - every future process starts with a `fork()`, so you can't actually change those parameters without messing with the zygote. (I'm simplifying but I'm pretty sure I'm right)

Answer (score 3):

I think @Delyan's answer hit the important points, but I wanted to add a few more details that didn't fit in a comment.

The official doc on doing this sort of thing is [Controlling the Embedded VM](http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/embedded-vm-control.html#execmode) ([in source tree](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/jb-mr2-release/docs/embedded-vm-control.html)).  The `execution-mode` property affects all apps, because the VM is only started once -- as "zygote" -- and all apps are launched by forking that process.

It's possible to change the mode of the VM once it has started, perhaps by introducing a new `VMRuntime` API call, but I don't think anybody has tried that and I'm not sure offhand how it would interact with the JIT compiler.

Most DEX optimization and verification is performed by dexopt before the app is ever launched, and the results are stored in the .odex file in `/data/dalvik-cache`, so tweaking `-Xdexopt` and `-Xverify` at app launch time may not do much (see [dexopt docs](http://milk.com/kodebase/dalvik-docs-mirror/docs/dexopt.html); [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/dalvik/+/jb-mr2-release/docs/dexopt.html)).

Comment: According to Controlling the Embedded VM: "If profiling is enabled or a debugger is attached, the VM switches to the "debug" interpreter. When profiling ends or the debugger disconnects, the original interpreter is resumed." So, it is possible switch different modes. Also, it is possible to run console applications with -Xint:portable flag whereas other applications run in the fast mode.

Comment: It's possible for the VM to choose to switch modes at certain times.  Changing the execution-mode setting won't immediately affect previously-executing threads, and there are other things (such as the profiling state) that the VM looks at when deciding how to run.  Setting the global interpreter mode when the VM starts up is documented and expected to work; changing it mid-execution may not do exactly what you expect.

Comment: Dalvik initializer in file dvmStartup sets all the necessary flags. According to my research It is called each time application launches. Here I changed gDvm.executionMode default to portable and everything worked Ok, but all aAndroid processes were in portable mode. I guess, if it is possible to check in this function whether it is necessary to change execution mode, my concept would work. But at this point I don't have an access to Dex file. It wasn't been read yet. As I understood, at this point Application Manager is called and then it in some magic way forks another process for my app.

Comment: fadden: Recently I have read that dalvik execution process is based on linux process (not surprisingly! :) ). The interesting thing from it - that linux processes ruled by Copy-on-Write. So, if we don't change some part of a child process, it part will not be mapped physicaly to it. Dalvik process contains necessary standart classes inside, which it loads during android system load. It means, if I understand correctly, if it forks new process, this new process will call libraries directly from the parent process. May be it is the point?