# How to launch only certain Android applications in portable execution mode?

Tags: android, apk, dalvik

My question is related to my previous one:

[How to pass dalvik command line parameters through .apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974968/how-to-pass-dalvik-command-line-parameters-through-apk)

Verification and optimization of Android applications are turned off.

I still want to launch my Android applications in **Portable** dalvik mode.
As far as I understood, it isn't possible to set some Manifest rules to gain this brave goal.

So I decided to change dalvik virtual machine!

I decided to change this function in file **/dalvik/vm/DvmDex.cpp**:

```
int dvmDexFileOpenFromFd(int fd, DvmDex** ppDvmDex)
{
    ...

    //MY CODE
    if (... file is my) {
        ALOGI("dvmDexFileOpenFromFd: changing mode to portable\n");
        gDvm.executionMode = kExecutionModeInterpPortable;
    }
    //MY CODE - END


    ...
}
```

It seems, that everything is OK. The message "dvmDexFileOpenFromFd: changing mode to portable" is in Android Log.
***"init"*** method is executed in **Portable** mode. But! ***"onCreate"*** method from some unclear reason is executed in **Fast** mode.

I have no idea what is happening, because, as far as I know, android application should be executed inside it's own process with it's own dalvik.

So could anybody shed light on this problem?

Why one part of my application is executed in **Fast** mode whereas other part in **Portable** mode?

And what should I do to force dalvik run in **Portable** mode only for my applications, if it is possible at all?

Comment: Fine, I'll bite: Why?

Comment: Is `gDvm.executionMode` changing?  If not, how are you detecting what mode the VM is running your code in?  Look at the code in `dvmInterpret()`; that actually calls into the interpreter entry point.

Comment: 323go: It's a long story. So, let's assume, that I just need it! ))

Comment: fadden: I added logging of all the portable instructions. There were any instruction from onCreate method. Also I added functions names logging and surprisingly there wasn't function onCreate in it. So, this function was called in some tricky way. As I understood it was called from Activity.java method performCreate. But it is situated within the same process. So, something unclear is happening! :)