# Is it possible to prepend bootclasspath for Dalvik VM on Android?

Tags: java, android, dalvik, bootclasspath

I'm experimenting with `-Xbootclasspath` in Java just for fun, and have added a test method `int java.lang.Object#id()`, just an instance-like `identityHashCode` method shortcut:

```java
package java.lang;

public class Object {

    public final int id() {
        return System.identityHashCode(this);
    }

// the original code goes here

}
```

The code above is compiled into a single-class JAR file, and the code below is compiled and dependent on the patch JAR file, thus the following code is legal:

```java
public static void main(final String... args) {
    System.out.println(new Object().id());
}
```

Running the sample application is quite easy prepending the bootstrap classes:

```
$ java -Xbootclasspath/p:patch.jar -cp app.jar test.Application
366712642
```

Works fine. Now, I wondering if it's possible to do the same trick on Android. So, the closest equivalent, I think, should be (from `adb shell`):

```
$ dalvikvm -Xbootclasspath:patch.jar -cp app.jar test.Application
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No virtual method id()I in class Ljava/lang/Object; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.lang.Object' appears in /syework/core-libart.jar)
    at test.Application.main(Application.java:11)
```

Looks like prepending, but not working since it's saying that the `java.lang.Object` class is already defined in another location (probably the real path is `/system/framework/core-libart.jar`, at least it says similar, but that JAR is quite different -- then how after all?). I also saw a few examples with the `$BOOTCLASSPATH` variable, but none of them works for me for some reason.

Is it possible to run `dalvikvm` overriding the bootclass path somehow and where are the core classes are loaded from?

EDIT 1:

It probably would work, but Android Dalvik VM is really dependent on the zygote that all new Dalvik VM processes are forked from, thus the zygote does not run with an alternative boot classpath. At least, this is what I understood from this question: [How to pass dalvik command line parameters through .apk?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18974968/how-to-pass-dalvik-command-line-parameters-through-apk)

Comment: You can try setting/overriding the BOOTCLASSPATH environment variable. I'm not sure if it will work though.

Comment: @JesusFreke thanks for the suggestion. I've seen that solution a few times earlier, but couldn't make it work for some reason unfortunately.

Comment: Oh, I see you mentioned that already, sorry! :)